# DeclareMathOperator and align environment

Tags: align, math-operators

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    \begin{align}
        &s + t &\text{foo}\\
        &\sin x &\text{bar}
    \end{align}
\end{document}
```

Here, the `\sin` (or any other operator declared with `\DeclareMathOperator`) is not aligned with the `s`, it has some spacing in front of it. I know that math operators are inserting some spacing such that `x \sin y` works as expected, but since there is nothing in front of the `\sin` here, I wouldn't expect that to apply. Typesetting the paragraph `\noindent\(s + t\)\\\(\sin x\)` works as expected, too, so why doesn't it align correctly when used with the align environment?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since the question already answers the cause of the space. The macro, defined by `\DeclareMathOperator` is defined as `\mathop` with additional spacing in some situations.

Here `align` adds an empty math ordinary atom to get correct spacing for binary or relation symbols. Also a space is added between `\mathord` and `\mathop`.

In this case the space can be avoided using an emtpy `\mathopen` in front of `\sin`. TeX does not insert a space between `\mathord` and `\mathopen` and between `\mathopen` and `\mathop`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    \begin{align}
        &s + t &\text{foo}\\
        &\mathopen{}\sin x &\text{bar}
    \end{align}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: @Manuel: Close, but there is a case left, a preceding punctuation atom. Putting `\mathclose` in `\scriptstyle` helps: `\begingroup\scriptstyle\mathclose{}\endgroup\mathord{<here the input>}\mathopen{}`

Answer (score 8):

The `align` environment expects a relation symbol after `&`, as the point of alignment, so there is an implicit `{}` at the beginning of the second column (and all other even numbered columns).

This has the unfortunate consequence that, if a math operator follows `&`, a thin space is added, because of TeX's spacing rules: when a math operator follows an ordinary atom a thin space is added, like in

```
$3\sin x$
```

which results in

> 3`<thin space>`sin`<thin space>`*x*

Solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  &s + t    &&\text{foo}\\
  &\!\sin x &&\text{bar}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Since a thin space is automatically added, because of the rule explained above, a `\!` will cancel it, because it's exactly the opposite of a thin space.

Note the `&&` before `\text`, so the conditions are left aligned.

---

Here's a set of variant environments where the automatic empty group is not added:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\patch@align@preamble}{\patchcmd{\align@preamble}{{}}{}{}{}}
\newenvironment{varalign}
 {\patch@align@preamble\start@align\@ne\st@rredfalse\m@ne}
 {\endalign}
\newenvironment{varalign*}
 {\patch@align@preamble\start@align\@ne\st@rredtrue\m@ne}
 {\endalign}
\newenvironment{varalignat}
 {\patch@align@preamble\start@align\z@\st@rredfalse}
 {\endalign}
\newenvironment{varalignat*}
 {\patch@align@preamble\start@align\z@\st@rredtrue}
 {\endalign}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{varalign}
  &s + t    &&\text{foo}\\
  &\sin x &&\text{bar}
\end{varalign}
text in between
\begin{varalign*}
  &s + t    &&\text{foo}\\
  &\sin x &&\text{bar}
\end{varalign*}
text in between
\begin{varalignat}{2}
  &s + t\qquad  &&\text{foo}\\
  &\sin x &&\text{bar}
\end{varalignat}
text in between
\begin{varalignat*}{2}
  &s + t\qquad    &&\text{foo}\\
  &\sin x &&\text{bar}
\end{varalignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think you should remark that `\!` is *exactly* the space you need to substract in such case, it's not just a “small amount of negative space”. I learned it rather late.